# Unresolved Reference in Python which is an integer

Tags: python

When I write the following code:

```
def demorgan(prop_sent, conditionals, candd):

    global sn
    d = 0
    while d < len(conditionals) -1:
        str1 = conditionals[d][4]
        if str1.find("~(") > -1:
            anc1 = conditionals[d][2]
```

The IDE says that d is an unresolved reference.  When I change the while loop to a for loop, which I can't do by the way, since the length of the conditionals list will change while looping, the error message goes away.

```
def demorgan(prop_sent, conditionals, candd):

    global sn

    for d in range(len(conditionals)):
        str1 = conditionals[d][4]
        if str1.find("~(") > -1:
            anc1 = conditionals[d][2]
```

I can't figure out why d is an unresolved reference in the while loop.  The bug also goes away when I simply put in:

```
while d < 10:
```

Comment: Could be a problem with your IDE. Doesn't look like a problem with `d`, other than the infinite loop.

Comment: I think it's an IDE bug. Which IDE are you using? Have you tried restarting or refreshing it?

Comment: It might help to include the full error, with stack trace.

Comment: Alternatively, if an error is not actually occurring, and it's just the IDE underlining that statement with a red squiggle but letting you run the code flawlessly anyway, it might help to include a screenshot of the squiggle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on second thought this is not an error.  My IDE editor (Pycharm) underlines the d variable and has a red flag in the right hand side, but when I actually step over the line, Python continues to work.  This is the only time I've seen when a red flag has gone up and Python has continued to work, so I guess the problem is with the IDE.

Comment: Time to update pycharm.  5.0.4 doesn't seem to have the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's just telling you that "d" is not such a good variable name?